# WIA Run-Time Check Failure #0 C++ (Windows Image Acquisition)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, wia

i try to use WIA to send data to a camera.
I need to develop this in C++ so i used the official "tutorial" on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wia/-wia-wia-tutorial
I know another project that works with C# and i want to do the same on C++
(C# Project on: https://github.com/pixeltris/SonyAlphaUSB)

When i want to use `Escape` Method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wia_xp/nf-wia_xp-iwiaitemextras-escape i get the

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.
This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling
convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

Error and i hope you can help me to resolve this. 
My code looks like this:

```
 //initialize wia
HRESULT h = CoInitialize(NULL);
IWiaDevMgr* pWiaDevMgr = NULL;
//create wia device manager
HRESULT hr = CreateWiaDeviceManager(&pWiaDevMgr);
//show connected devices and get deviceId
BSTR bstrDeviceID = SysAllocString(L"");
HRESULT hr2 = EnumerateWiaDevices(pWiaDevMgr, &bstrDeviceID);
//create device with device id
IWiaItem* ppWiaDevice;
HRESULT hr3 = CreateWiaDevice(pWiaDevMgr, bstrDeviceID, &ppWiaDevice);

//case IWiaItem to IWiaItemExtras
IWiaItemExtras* ppWiaExtra = (IWiaItemExtras*)ppWiaDevice;

//try to send data
DWORD dwEscapeCode = 256;
BYTE* lpInData = new unsigned char[37]{ 0x01, 0x92, 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x01 ,
    0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 ,
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x03 ,
    0x00 ,   0x00 , 0x00 , 0x03 , 0x00 , 0x00 , 0x00 }; 
DWORD cbInDataSize = sizeof(lpInData);

BYTE* pOutData = new unsigned char[4]{ 0x00 , 0x00,0x00, 0x00};
DWORD dwOutDataSize = sizeof(pOutData);

DWORD pdwActualDataSize = NULL;

BSTR bstre = SysAllocString(L"");
//just to test if ppWiaExtra is working
HRESULT hr6 = ppWiaExtra->GetExtendedErrorInfo(&bstre); //works
//try to send data with Escape Method
//see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wia_xp/nf-wia_xp-iwiaitemextras-escape
HRESULT hr5 = ppWiaExtra->Escape(dwEscapeCode, lpInData, cbInDataSize, pOutData, dwOutDataSize, &pdwActualDataSize); //Run-Time Check Failure #0
```

The Methods i use are the same as in the example code on https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wia/wiassamp/wiassamp.cpp

The Escape Method is:

```
virtual /* [helpstring] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Escape( 
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwEscapeCode,
        /* [size_is][in] */ __RPC__in_ecount_full(cbInDataSize) BYTE *lpInData,
        /* [in] */ DWORD cbInDataSize,
        /* [length_is][size_is][out] */ __RPC__out_ecount_part(dwOutDataSize, pdwActualDataSize ? *pdwActualDataSize : dwOutDataSize) BYTE *pOutData,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwOutDataSize,
        /* [out] */ __RPC__out DWORD *pdwActualDataSize) = 0;
```

So how can i find the actual problem why the error is shown and how can i resolve it?

(I use WIA1 because WIA2 doesn't find the device)

```
STDMETHODCALLTYPE
```

is defined in winnt.h as following:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_MPPC_)

// Win32 doesn't support __export

#ifdef _68K_
#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE       __cdecl
#else
#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE       __stdcall
#endif
#define STDMETHODVCALLTYPE      __cdecl

#define STDAPICALLTYPE          __stdcall
#define STDAPIVCALLTYPE         __cdecl

#else

#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE       __export __stdcall
#define STDMETHODVCALLTYPE      __export __cdecl

#define STDAPICALLTYPE          __export __stdcall
#define STDAPIVCALLTYPE         __export __cdecl

#endif
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
GetExtendedErrorInfo
```

now returns Not Implemented Error (but that's currently not so important for me)

The bigger Problem is that

```
ppWiaExtra->Escape
```

returns `E_FAIL` and that one is unspecified, i think it's some `pointer` problem again or an issue with my usage of `sizeof`

Comment: That error usually occurs if the function you're calling has a `__stdcall` calling convention, and your code is using the `__cdecl` convention, or vice-versa.  Where is the evidence that the function you're calling can be `virtual`?

Comment: STDMETHODCALLTYPE is defined as followed (in winnt.h)
'#ifdef _68K_
#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE       __cdecl
#else
#define STDMETHODCALLTYPE       __stdcall
#endif
#define STDMETHODVCALLTYPE      __cdecl'
and 'virtual' (All the code of the Escape Method) i can find either in wia_lh.h or wia_xp.h (parameters are exactly the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> IWiaItemExtras* ppWiaExtra = (IWiaItemExtras*)ppWiaDevice;
> ```

This line is not correct; you can't just cast pointers to get different COM interfaces. That's what [QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/queryinterface?view=vs-2019) is for:

```
IWiaItemExtras* ppWiaExtra;
HRESULT result = ppWiaDevice->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&ppWiaExtra));
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it - now i get that hr6 (GetExtendedErrorInfo) is not implemented (not so important for me)
but Escape is returning E_FAIL - that's an unspecified error, probably some issues with sizeof() ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using sizeof at all. The API asks for the number of bytes in each argument (37 and 4, respectively) and you're instead passing in the size of a pointer in bytes. I recommend spending some time reading examples of using Win32 APIs in C++ in general to learn how common patterns work.

Comment: Well there's not any useful information about WIA C++ i can find beside the information on the Microsoft docs page. This also doesn't help with some "Unknown failure" - also running examples that actually work and are open source are pretty rare.

Comment: I said "using Win32 APIs in C++ in general"; neither of the issues you've had so far have been specific to WIA. Both QueryInterface and array-as-pointer-plus-length are very common patterns in Win32.